# How to copy data into every other cell in a row?

Tags: excel, vba, offset, paste

I copy cells (`B18:B23`) from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` while transposing.

I want to paste to every other column (`O4`,`Q4`,`S4`, etc. skipping a cell between).

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim wsDst As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        
    wsSrc.Range("B18:B23").Copy
    wsDst.Offset(1, 1).Range("O4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
       
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I've gotten it to transpose. How do I skip every other column when it pastes?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a "skip/transpose" using the standard Copy/Paste method, so I think the best option would be to loop through your values and use an offset. This should do it...

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDst As Worksheet, aCell As Range, tOff As Long
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
        For Each aCell In wsSrc.Range("B18:B23").Cells
            wsDst.Range("o4").Offset(0, tOff).Value = aCell.Value
            tOff = tOff + 2

        Next aCell

End Sub
```