# Macro - Copy a Range & Paste the data in every other cell into empty row bellow solution

Tags: excel, vba

I grabbed this great solution from here. Works great.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58793917/16408824

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDst As Worksheet, aCell As Range, tOff As Long
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDst = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
        For Each aCell In wsSrc.Range("B18:B23").Cells
            wsDst.Range("o4").Offset(0, tOff).Value = aCell.Value
            tOff = tOff + 2

        Next aCell

End Sub
```

The only problem I have is that the data in the range in sheet 1 changes, and when it does I need to paste it to sheet 2 in the row below the old data to be able to keep both the older data and the new. I am using the vba code above to copy and paste, but the problem is it always pastes in the same place, not a new row. Offsetting by (1,T0ff) doesn't help as it pastes only the 1st cell correctly the rest is offset by 2 rows.

Any idea, please?

Comment: Find the last row used on second page `LastRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to make your VBA code dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub CopyData()
    
    Dim cDst As Range, aCell As Range
    
    'find the first destination cell (below any existing data)
    Set cDst = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    For Each aCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B18:B23").Cells
        cDst.Value = aCell.Value
        Set cDst = cDst.Offset(0, 2) 'next destination cell
    Next aCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works well, the only issue is, it doesn't transpose.